# Vue.js: "attach" content to two different classes?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

So, I have data in my vue.js file that I want to "attach" to two different classes without having to create another Vue.js component or repeating the content again in another component. For example:

```
var fullViewContent = new Vue({
  el: ".class-one",
  data: {
    name: 'Vue.js'
  },
  data: {
    items: [{
      content: "repeat this string in various places",

    },
   ]
 }
```

First HTML Block

```
  <div class="class-one">
      <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <div class="container">
           <h2>{{ item.content }}</h2>
        </div>
      </template>
  </div><!-- end list view -->
```

Second HTML Block

```
  <div class="different-html-block class-one">
      <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <div class="container">
           <h2>{{ item.content }}</h2>
        </div>
      </template>
  </div><!-- end list view -->
```

So I want the same content from my component in each of these different html blocks. Is it enough to just attach the same class to it? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot apply a Vue to more than one element.

Instead, move the shared data into an object accessible to both Vues.

```
const shared = {
  items: [
    {
      content: "repeat this string in various places",
    },
    {
      content: "more data",
    },
   ]
}

var app1 = new Vue({
  el: "#app1",
  data: {
    name: 'Vue.js',
    items: shared.items
  },
})

var app2 = new Vue({
  el: "#app2",
  data: {
    name: 'Vue.js',
    items: shared.items
  }
})
```

And the template

```
<div id="app1">
  <div class="class-one">
      <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <div class="container">
           <h2>{{ item.content }}</h2>
        </div>
      </template>
  </div><!-- end list view -->
</div>

<div id="app2">
  <div class="different-html-block class-one">
      <template v-for="(item, index) in items">
        <div class="container">
           <h2>{{ item.content }}</h2>
        </div>
      </template>
  </div><!-- end list view -->
</div>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/XMOYKK?editors=1010).

If you want to avoid repeating code you can programmatically create your Vues.

```
each = Array.prototype.forEach;

const data = {
  name: "Vue.js",
  items: [
    {
      content: "repeat this string in various places",
    },
    {
      content: "more data",
    },
   ]
}

each.call(document.querySelectorAll(".class-one"), el => new Vue({el, data}))
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/LWqrxz?editors=1010).